# ios 8 Storyboard Search Bar Too Wide

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode6, autolayout

I'm using a search bar through Storyboard and when I view in the simulator it looks like this... (You can see how the right side is cut off)

[image]

How do I fix this and make it perfectly fit into the screen? In storyboard, it looks fine.

My storyboard is set to Compact Width, Any Height. AutoLayout is on.

Comment: What if you set the simulated ViewController's size to iPhone 6 e.g.?

Comment: Add the correct layout constrains for the search bar. Particularly in case of the search bar in the image, make sure that 'Trailing Space to Superview' is equal to 0.

Comment: @LinusG. it already is

Comment: But what simulator do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add constraints! Just hold the `control` key on your keyboard and drag anywhere inside the searchBar and tick the `Width` option or tick the `trailing space to container margin` by dragging it to the right of your searchBar.

**Or else**

Click on the searchBar and do this :

[image]

Comment: When I do that, I can no longer see the search bar. I believe it goes under the navigation bar. See here: http://imgur.com/1UOpR6W.png

Comment: I even tried adding a height constraint but it's still same as above, under the navigation bar.

Comment: Add more constraints. Drag towards the top of the searchBar and tick 'leading space to container margin'

Comment: I'm only getting the option "Aspect Ratio" not "leading space to container margin"

Comment: Thats because you are still dragging within the searchBar. The simplest thing to do is to click the line below the value '269' in the image above(sorry I couldn't describe it in text).

Answer (score 1):

can you disable the auto-layout and use the autoresizing mask. or try dragging your bar to right and set `trailing space to container margin`. It will stop your search bar to go outside the screen.